# How do I show custom recent posts in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

Now it's showing like this: [now it's showing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9PP6.png)

I want it to look like this: [I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApCJI.jpg)

Comment: To look like you will need to provide more information.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do:

1. In your WordPress dashboard, go to Appearance » Widgets and add the ‘Recent Posts’ widget to your sidebar.
   https://prnt.sc/1rhjdc4
2. Using wp query

> ```
> $args = array(
>     'post_type'      => 'product',
>     'posts_per_page' => 10,
> );
> $loop = new WP_Query($args);
> while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
>     $loop->the_post();
>     ?>
>     <div class="entry-content">
>         <?php the_title(); ?>
>         <?php the_content(); ?>
>     </div>
>     <?php
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

wp_get_recent_posts( array $args = array(), string $output = ARRAY_A )
Please read this article
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/

  ```
  <?php
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
  foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
      printf( '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>',
          esc_url( get_permalink( $recent['ID'] ) ),
          apply_filters( 'the_title', $recent['post_title'], $recent['ID'] )
      );
  }
  ```
  ?>

Comment: Please edit your answer and place code in `code` blocks, properly, your `?>` is outside the blocks.